# Получение значения из radio btn

Tags: html, jquery, radio

Есть некая форма с radio.

При некотором событии, функция (ниже) принимает форму и возвращает значение выбранного пункта. Проблема в том, что всегда принимает значение последнего пункта, вне зависимости какой выбран.

Вопрос в том как исправить функцию, чтобы бралось значение выбранного пункта?

```js
// соберет объет вида {name: value, name: value}
function getFormArray($form) {
    var formData = {};
    var formFill = true;

    $form.find(':input').each(function() {
        value = $.trim(this.value);
        if (value.length == 0) {
            setError($(this));
            formFill = false;
        } else
            formData[this.name] = value;
    });
    return (!formFill) ? formFill : formData;
}

console.log(getFormArray($('#form')));

$(document).on('click', 'input', function() {
    console.log(getFormArray($('#form')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="1"> 1
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="2"> 2 
  <input type="text" name="st" value="4"> 3 
  <input type="text" name="sr" value="3"> 4
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="5"> 5
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте, выбрана ли радио-кнопка, прежде чем совершать манипуляции с `this.value`.

```
var formFill = false;
$form.find(':input').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      var value = $.trim(this.value);
      if (value.length == 0) {
        setError($(this));
      } else {
        formData[this.name] = value;
        formFill = true; 
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: если помимо `radio` будет и `input type='text'` , придется проверять отдельно каждый?

Comment: @ИльяБалабуев `if (this.type != 'radio' && this.type != 'checkbox' || this.checked)` или что-то типа того

Comment: @ИльяБалабуев Не понял. Объясните, чего Вы хотите добиться. Желательно - путем редактирования вопроса.

Comment: @Igor судя по названию функции, она задумывалась для сбора всех значений всех полей формы любых типов. А вы её переписали на обработку только radio и тем самым сломали :)

Comment: @Igor Поправил вопрос. прощу прощения, что сразу не сделал.

Comment: @andreymal - "возвращает значение выбранного пункта" - по-моему, так :)